# How to set test coverage threshold of new code only (Jest)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

How to set coverage checking of every new chunk of code before merging and skip this particular merge if test coverage of new code in it is less than 80%? We already have the global threshold of 80% but this setting doesn't assume that each pull request will be covered with tests less than 80% (some can be covered with 60% and some with 100% - it's unfair).
Stack (React, Next, Jest)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Gedrimas did you find an option for this?